# What happens when you skew a rectangle in SVG?

Tags: svg, transformation, skew

Here is my code:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <rect
    x="100"
    y="50"
    width="100"
    height="30"
    fill="none"
    stroke="black"
  />
  <rect
    x="100"
    y="50"
    width="100"
    height="30"
    fill="tomato"
    fill-opacity="0.5"
    transform="skewX(45)"
  />
  <rect
    x="100"
    y="50"
    width="100"
    height="30"
    fill="steelblue"
    fill-opacity="0.5"
    transform="skewY(45)"
  />
</svg>
```

I'm trying to understand what's happening.
I made this draw to simulate `skewX(45)`. Is that right? How can I compute the new skewed rectangle coordinates?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, but everything is skewed from the top-left corner (coordinates `0,0`). It's easier to see if we include a grid to represent the coordinate system. Play around with this example:

```js
(function() {
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            skewDirection: 'skewX',
            skewDegrees: 45,
        },
        computed: {
            myTransform() {
                return `${this.skewDirection}(${this.skewDegrees})`;
            }
        },
    })
})();
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
    background: #444;
}
button, input, select {
    font: inherit;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#tools {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1em;
    padding: .5em;
    background: silver;
}
#tools label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
svg {
    overflow: visible;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<main id="app">
    <div id="tools">
        <ul>
            <li><label><input type="radio" v-model="skewDirection" value="skewX"/>skewX</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="radio" v-model="skewDirection" value="skewY"/>skewY</label></li>
        </ul>
        <input type="range" v-model:number="skewDegrees" max="89"/>
        <output>{{ skewDegrees }}</output>
    </div>

    <svg width="300" height="300">
        <defs>
            <!-- https://codepen.io/pigabo/pen/eAiLF -->
            <pattern id="smallGrid" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <path d="M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="0.5"/>
            </pattern>
            <pattern id="grid" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#smallGrid)"/>
                <path d="M 100 0 L 0 0 0 100" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1"/>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <g id="targets" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="10">
            <rect x="100" y="50" width="100" height="30" transform="skewX(45)" />
            <rect x="100" y="50" width="100" height="30" transform="skewY(45)" />
        </g>
        <g id="world" :transform="myTransform">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)" />
            <rect x="100" y="50" width="100" height="30" fill="tomato" fill-opacity=".7" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</main>
```